# AC small signal analysis of BJT nework

Tags: transistors

Why do we set the input voltage to zero (short circuit) when calculating the output impedance of a transistor network?

Why don't we set the output voltage to zero (short circuit) for input impedance calculations?

Comment: Firstly we don't and secondly, because output voltage level (via feedback) can totally redefine the input impedance we can't assume it's zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable question and the answer is straightforward.

When finding the equivalent impedance of a port, one may zero the *independent sources* within the circuit and then either calculate the impedance directly or use the test source method.

Now, the input voltage is an independent source, an independent *variable*, that is a *stimulus* to the circuit.

We are free to set the input voltage to zero or anything we wish and ask "given this input voltage, what is the output voltage"?

Changing the input voltage *does not change the circuit under consideration*.  It is simply a change in the stimulus to the circuit.

However, *the output voltage is not a source that is "applied" to the circuit*.  It is not a stimulus; it is a *dependent* variable.

*Forcing* the output voltage to be zero volts, i.e., placing a short circuit across the output, *changes the circuit* under consideration and thus, isn't a valid move to find the input impedance.  In other words, finding the input impedance with the output shorted is finding the input impedance of a *different circuit*.